# Tapkey Mobile SDK logInAsync with 400 error

Tags: tapkey

I am trying to use Tapkey Mobile SDK on iOS with access token from Token Exchange flow. It fails with error

```
'https://my.tapkey.com/api/v1/Auth/Auth/UserInfo?t=tk' completed with code 400
```

Error message doesn't say much. How can I debug what exactly is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TKMServiceFactory.userManager.logInAsync` returns a `TKMPromise`.
https://developers.tapkey.io/mobile/ios/reference/TapkeyMobileLib/latest/Classes/TKMPromise.html

You have to catch Error for getting more informations about the issue

```
 .catchOnUI { asyncError -> [TYPE] in 
   let error = asyncError.syncSrcError
}
```

The Error will probably be an TKMError which contains ErrorCodes and ErrorMessages:
https://developers.tapkey.io/mobile/ios/reference/TapkeyMobileLib/latest/Classes/TKMError.html

**EDIT**

When using an own Identity Provider, the user has to be registered before the user is able to login in:

https://developers.tapkey.io/api/authentication/identity_providers/#working-with-users

Comment: Error code is `RestHandler.ServerError` and error message is `REST POST call to \'https://my.tapkey.com/api/v1/Auth/Auth/UserInfo?t=tk\' returned response: 400 ` . Which doesn't explain anything specific about the error. Does that mean the token is wrong?

Comment: No. An invalid token would result in 401. In cases of 400 it usually means that there is a misconfiguration of your oAuth setup or a precondition is not satisfied.
Usually the  the ErrorCode contains information about the specific error. But in this particularly obviously not. Please send a email with referring this thread and your oAuth ClientId to Tapkey support. They will lookup the particularly issue.

Comment: Thanks @Harald. I was able to create a user for Identity Provider. How can we authenticate that particular user? Should we encrypt user id to the JWT somehow?

Comment: You don't have to specify the Tapkey UserId inside the jwt token.
If the user is preregistered it is sufficient to specify your userId in the subject of the jwt token.
https://developers.tapkey.io/api/authentication/identity_providers/#creating-jwt-tokens